# Why does this method for weighting grid cells result in tiny values?

Tags: python, netcdf, grid-spacing

I'm working with a bunch of netCDF files for uni, hence the `for loop`. Its global coverage data, and because the Earth is not flat, we need to weight the pixels/grid cells of the data to make sure we have an accurate value for the mean (otherwise certain points that take up way more area i.e. near the poles, will contribute more the the mean than they should). What I am trying to do here is first weight each pixel, then get the spatial average of the variable, here called 'var'. Here is my code for it:

```
    for filename in os.listdir(indir): # indir = /path/to/directoy
        input_file = os.path.join(indir, filename)
        output_file = os.path.join(outdir, filename) # outdir = /path/to/directoy
        ds = xr.open_dataset(input_file)
  
        R = 6.371e6  # radius of Earth in m
        dphi=np.deg2rad(2.5) # degs between lat, in metadata of ds
        dlambda = np.deg2rad(2.5) # degrees between lons 

        dlat = R * dphi*xr.ones_like(ds.var.lon)
        dlon = R * dlambda*np.cos(np.deg2rad(ds.var.lat))
        cell_area = dlon*dlat

        da_area = cell_area.broadcast_like(ds.var) # to get to same shape as ds
        total_area=da_area.sum(['lat','lon'])
        ds_weighted = ((ds['var']*da_area)/total_area)

        fldmean = ds_weighted.mean(dim=['lat', 'lon'], skipna=True)
        fldmean.to_netcdf(output_file)
        ds.close()
```

Its based on [this example](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-correct-way-to-average-the-globe-92ceecd172b7). I also tried to keep the names here as simple as possible, hence they are pretty generic.

I don't get any errors when I run it, and it saves just fine where I need it to. The resulting time series plot also looks good - but the values are tiny, like 2.4743e-6, where I am expecting somewhere between 5 and 15, so its many magnitudes out. For the life of me, I can't see what is so different here to the example in the link. I guess it must be something to do with the divide to get such small numbers, but its also how its done in the link and also makes some logical sense. Any ideas?

footnote: This is also 'area weighting' rather than 'latitude weighting', this is because I'm trying to do a comparison with the `fldmean` function in CDO (Climate Data Operators), which uses area weighting. I'm still getting my head around if it makes much difference, but I still want to stay as close as possible to this operator!

Comment: I'm probably misinterpreting the xr.ones_like but you're not explicitly converting the ds.var.lon to radians, as far as I can tell. And, are you converting to radians later before calculating the total area?